# active dropdown menu in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

i try to create a dropdown menu in bootstrap but it doesnt work!
    i try many samples in w3schools but none of them work:(

```
 <!-- links -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <!-- My Code -->
<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .dropdown class is used to indicate a dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>Use the .dropdown-menu class to actually build the dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown".</p>                                          
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you've posted works so what precisely does "none of them work mean"?

Comment: Works here -> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMKaYd. Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Try to complete the markup. Works fine in here.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- links -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- My Code -->
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
            <p>The .dropdown class is used to indicate a dropdown menu.</p>
            <p>Use the .dropdown-menu class to actually build the dropdown menu.</p>
            <p>To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown".</p>                                          
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @alirezasafian Yes it is possible to comment this, but I think showing how to do it is much better.